# Инициализация Enum в классе

Tags: java, enum

Как быть с такой конструкцией? Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> Error:(112, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable Fdg

```
class A {
    public enum Fdg { Red, Blue, Green }
    public Fdg f;
    public int i;
}

class B {
    A = new A();
    A.f = Fdg.One; ///в этом месте ошибка
    public in i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно быть примерно так:

```
class A
{
    enum Fdg
    {
        Red, Blue, Green
    }

    public Fdg f;
    public int i;
}

class B
{
    A a = new A();
    public int i;

    public B()
    {
        a.f = A.Fdg.Red;
    }
}
```

По ошибкам:

1. `A = new A();` - *<indentifier> expected*. Должно быть указано имя создаваемой переменной класса `A`.
2. `A.f = Fdg.One;`.

   - присвоение поля объекта должно быть внутри метода или конструктора.
   - для доступа к `Fdg` нужно использовать `A.Fdg`.
   - в `Fdg` нет значения `One`. Видимо, подразумевается `Red`.
3. `public in i;` - либо где-то есть класс `in`, либо всё же должно быть `int`.

Comment: Если я вынес за класс А  и логика сохранена у этого класса в своем файле свои константы и перечисления. Спасибо

Comment: @Mikhail ваше первое предложение я не понял. И запятых там нет, и, видимо, несколько мыслей сразу описано

Comment: Если я вынес  enum из класса А . Присвоение поля происходит в конструкторе класса B. пример для наглядности. Мне надо было сохранить логику- Класс со своими константами и полями в своем файле. Все так и получилось

Comment: Да мысли заняты и пишу чепуху)))

Comment: @Mikhail Если класс `A` находится в собственном файле, то тогда вопросов к `enum` нет. Я почему-то подумал, что у вас оба класса являются подклассами основного класса. Если вас вариант с выносом инициализации поля `a` в конструктор устраивает, не забудьте принять ответ.

Comment: @Mikhail ответ я подправил под вариант с классами в разных файлах.

Answer (score 0):

Надо импорт делать:

```
import пакет_где_лежит_A.Fdg;
```

или

```
import пакет_где_лежит_A.*;
```

P.S. ну и не `Fdg.One`, а `Fdg.Red` тогда уж.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Fdg{Red,Blue,Green}
...
A.f=Fdg.One;/// в этом месте ошибка
```

One не существует же. Добавте его в enum Fdg

Comment: для наглядности писал поэтому запутался. Правильно RED